# Glitch in Windows 7 Notepad (Microsoft)

Tags: windows-7, notepad

I am having problems with notepad, particular when I am copying and pasting this text:

Sorry jeg siger det. Kan ikke lide dig mere. Du dømmer dem med lala Berlin tørklæder. Øøøhhh du render rundt med en Michael kors taske og viser Hvsd du får og køber. Det sgu da det samme "åh jeg viser Hvor rig jeg er" ja du laver yt som mange andre. Dem der har det skide lala Berlin tørklæder har det og's og bære det lige som mange andre. Ja! Vi får inspiration fra andre altså. Stop med af døm, det er bare lavt.

Can anyone reproduce this problem? The font becomes inconsistent in wordwrap mode.

[image: Here is what I see]

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Try Microsoft Word instead

Comment: I thought about making an answer with "I am unable to reproduce this" and putting a screenshot :D   I am, however, unable to reproduce on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 Build 7601, SP1. I'm using US English for everything.

Does it happen every time and only when copying and pasting? Is it only happening if it's copied from a particular source? (I copied it from your question into notepad). What happens if you manually type it?